# How to use good parameter in rtabmap_ros (stereo_mapping.launch)

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, rtabmap, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get good parameter on rqt_reconfig  this dont have speckle but when roslaunch rtabmap_ros stereo_mapping.launch stereo_namespace:="/stereo_camera" rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" approximate_sync:=true My map have speckle
how to use parameter on mapping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227732/how-to-use-good-parameter-in-rtabmap_ros-(stereo_mapping.launch)/) by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-27**:
What do you mean when you say "I get good parameter on rqt_reconfig" ? Are you using rqt_reconfig to modify the default parameters?

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-02-27**:
Yes,  result is good (/stereo_camera/points2 ) but when i launch rtabmap_ros stereo_mapping.launch ,i get voxel_cloud ,it have speckle yet  why`?  stereo_camera/points2 what to do

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-28**:
I still don't understand. Maybe a few pictures or screenshots would help.

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-02-28**:
can I use stereo Hand-Held Mapping of Rtabmap  use to pointcloud2(stereo_camera/points2) from stereo_image_poc  to make map ? if it not use what should I calibrate disparity map? (voxel_cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rtabmap regenerates the disparity image for visualization, so ignoring the parameters you set for [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc). If you want to use the disparity image generated from [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc), I recommend to do something similar to [Stereo A setup](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Stereo_A) by generating a depth image from the disparity image (with [rtabmap_ros/disparity_to_depth](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros.2BAC8-disparity_to_depth) nodelet) and then use [rgbd_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/rgbd_mapping.launch) instead of [stereo_mapping.launch](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/launch/stereo_mapping.launch).

```
<group ns="/stereo_camera" >
    <node pkg="stereo_image_proc" type="stereo_image_proc" name="stereo_image_proc"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="disparity2depth" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/disparity_to_depth"/>
</group>
```

Launch:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rgbd_mapping.launch rgb_topic:=/stereo_camera/left/image_rect_color depth_registered_topic:=/stereo_camera/depth camera_info_topic:=/stereo_camera/left/camera_info rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start"
```

Note that the next rtabmap version will have [mostly the same parameters](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/blob/be559c181a7b46119438170f8a52d0b747d2d2a4/corelib/include/rtabmap/core/Parameters.h#L437-L445) as stereo_image_proc to tune the regenerated disparity image.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-03-01**:
Can I use other Odometry ?  in **Stereo A setup** except (viso2_ros)

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-03-01**:
Yes, you can. You will then have something similar to [Kinect+Odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_Odometry) setup.

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-03-13**:
Check my code, please? Under comment

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-03-27**:
Can I use input from video file for mapping ?
because my computer spec is low ,It is slower than real time

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-03-29**:
Well, the best way to do that is to record a rosbag and replay it at a lower rate.

**Comment by [Greenout](https://answers.ros.org/users/26098/greenout/) on 2016-03-29**:
can I use image render?